# How to pass the value of variables from main class to another class?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, return-type

Hello everyone I'm currently creating a simple program. I have 2 classes the first one is calculator and the second one is parameters_return. What I want to happen is that when I read the  values of x and y in my second class i want to use them in my first class Unfortunately, I can't run the program because it has an error. The code is below please help me with regards to this matter. I'm just self studying I really want to learn Java.

Code in (first class) calculator class is:

```java
class calculator {
    //with parameters with return type
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }

    //with parameters without return type
    void sub(int a, int b) {
        System.out.print(a - b);
    }

    //without parameters with return type
    int mul() {
        parameters_return s1 = new parameters_return();
        int c = (s1.x) * (s1.y);
        return c;
    }

    //without parameters without return type
    void div() {
        parameters_return s2 = new parameters_return();
        int c = (s2.x) / (s2.y);
        System.out.println("Division = " + c);
    }
}
```

Code in my (second class) parameters_return class is:

```java
class parameters_return {
    int x, y;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt();
        calculator perform = new calculator();

        //addition
        int z = perform.add(x, y);
        System.out.println("Added value = " + z);

        //subtraction
        System.out.println("Subtracted value = ");
        perform.sub(x, y);

        //multiplication
        z = perform.mul();
        System.out.println("Multiplication value = ");

        //division
        perform.div();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get values from main class and can be used in another class?

Comment: You need to pass your variables into the methods just like you did with the add and sub methods. What you are trying to do (pulling local variables from a static main method into your objects instance methods) can not and will not work for a myriad of technical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
class ParametersReturn {
    static int x, y;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt();
        Calculator perform = new Calculator();

        //addition
        int z = perform.add(x, y);
        System.out.println("Added value = " + z);

        //subtraction
        System.out.println("Subtracted value = ");
        perform.sub(x, y);

        //multiplication
        z = perform.mul();
        System.out.println("Multiplication value = " + z);

        //division
        perform.div();
    }
}
```

This should be your ParametersReturn Class and make sure you should start your class name with capital letter , you are using Scanner class to use it you have to import java.util package. And to use these variables in Calculator class make these variables static

```
class Calculator {
    //with parameters with return type
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }

    //with parameters without return type
    void sub(int a, int b) {
        System.out.print(a - b);
    }

    //without parameters with return type
    int mul() {
        ParametersReturn s1 = new ParametersReturn();
        int c = (s1.x) * (s1.y);
        return c;
    }

    //without parameters without return type
    void div() {
        ParametersReturn s2 = new ParametersReturn();
        int c = (s2.x) / (s2.y);
        System.out.println("Division = " + c);
    }
}
```

And in multiplication you forgot to print the value of z